# Solving a PDE equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Could you please help me to solve this equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}E(x,t)-LC_1 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E(x,t)+LC_2  \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \partial t^2}E(x,t)=0 \qquad \qquad t \ge0,\qquad 0\le x\le l$$ 
$$E(0,t)=0 \qquad E(l,t)=V \qquad E(x,0)=\frac{x}{l}V$$
$$E(x,t)=?$$
L, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are positive constants.

Thanks

Comment: For example, $E\equiv 0$ is a solution. You can also find a few polynomials that solve it. Are there any boundary conditions?

Comment: There are boundaries that I added.@Rafflesia arnoldii

Comment: You may be interested to know that where this equation comes from? This equation shows the voltage of transformer winding in transient state which "t" shows time and "x" shows the position of each component of winding.

Comment: You didn't specify $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}(x,0)$. You need this information to specify the problem. In particular, in this case if $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}(x,0) \equiv 0$ then your initial condition will simply stay where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDE
$$
E_{xxtt} + a E_{xx} - b E_{tt} = 0 
$$

assuming 
$$
E(x, t) = f(x) \, g(t) \quad (*)
$$ 
thus using separation of variables
then
\begin{align}
0 
&= f''(x) \, g''(t) + a \, f''(x) \, g(t) - b \, f(x) \, g''(t) \\
&= (f''(x) - b \, f(x)) \, g''(t) + a \, f''(x)g(t)
\end{align}
and then
$$
b \frac{f(x)}{f''(x)} - 1 = a \frac{g(t)}{g''(t)} = c = \mbox{const.}
$$
gives two ODEs
$$
f''(x) - \frac{b}{c+1} f(x) = 0 \quad g''(t) - \frac{a}{c} g(t) = 0
$$
Depending of the constant $c$ being positive or negative this would give some exponential solutions or some oscillation each.

Applying the boundary conditions:

- $E(0,t) = 0$ would imply $f(0) = 0$.
- $E(x,0) = (x / l) \, V$ would imply $f(x) g(0) = (x/l) V$
- $E(l, t) = V$ would imply $f(l) g(t) = V$

That last one seems not satisfiable by a separable solution $(*)$ to me. So much for this solution attempt.

Comment: Then you need to assemble a solution satisfying the initial and boundary conditions from the separable solutions.

Comment: You are faster than me. :-)